# Uncaught ReferenceError: rowOffset is not defined

Tags: javascript, dom, webpack

I'm making a gem-puzzle. When I just use html and js I generate elements dynamically and put onclick on each one and when I click on it, everything works well, but when I connected the webpack it doesn't work. I rewrite the function showTable with createElement instead concatenation. And now I have no error with the function moveThisTile, but now there is an error Uncaught ReferenceError: rowOffset is not defined, which calculate the coordinates for the new tile location. How can it fixed?
This is a full code with an error https://codepen.io/tomas777/pen/abZjZav
Please, help

```
function showTable() {
    let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
    document.querySelector('#table').appendChild(tbody);
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      if (arrayForBoard[i][j] == 0) {
        let cell = document.createElement("td");
        cell.className = 'blank';
      } else {
        let cell = document.createElement("td");
        cell.className = 'tile';
        cell.onclick = moveThisTile(i, j); 
        cell.innerHTML =arrayForBoard[i][j];
      }
      row.appendChild(cell);
    } 
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  } 
};

function moveThisTile(tableRow, tableColumn) {
  if (checkIfMoveable(tableRow, tableColumn, "up") ||
      checkIfMoveable(tableRow, tableColumn, "down") ||
      checkIfMoveable(tableRow, tableColumn, "left") ||
      checkIfMoveable(tableRow, tableColumn, "right") ) {
    incrementMoves();
  } else {
    alert("ERROR: Cannot move tile!\nTile must be next to a blank space.");
  }
  if (checkIfWinner()) {
    alert("Congratulations! You solved the puzzle in " + moves + " moves.");
    startNewGame();
  }
}

function checkIfMoveable(rowCoordinate, columnCoordinate, direction) {
  rowOffset = 0;
  columnOffset = 0;
  if (direction == "up"){rowOffset = -1;}
  else if (direction == "down"){rowOffset = 1;}
  else if (direction == "left"){columnOffset = -1;}
  else if (direction == "right"){columnOffset = 1;}  
  if (rowCoordinate + rowOffset >= 0 && columnCoordinate + columnOffset >= 0 &&
    rowCoordinate + rowOffset < rows && columnCoordinate + columnOffset < columns
  ){
    if ( arrayForBoard[rowCoordinate + rowOffset][columnCoordinate + columnOffset] == 0){
      arrayForBoard[rowCoordinate + rowOffset][columnCoordinate + columnOffset] = arrayForBoard[rowCoordinate][columnCoordinate];
      arrayForBoard[rowCoordinate][columnCoordinate] = 0;
      showTable();
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false; 
}
```

Comment: The codepen doesn't show a game or maybe I am not sure how to play the game.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman because due to an error it is not displayed

Comment: "cell" is not defined at row.appendChild(cell);
you can debug it, and see why cell is not what you expect

Comment: "let cell" inside if block makes cell private to the "if" block. If you try to use that variable outside, it's not available

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman this is how it should to be https://codepen.io/tomas777/pen/abZjmZp , but with webpack it show error with moveThisTile, so i rewrite it and now anothe error

Comment: @Tom Checking again.

Comment: @Victor and how I can rewrite it?

Comment: @Tom Dude, I ended up playing and getting addicted!  But it works fine in my browser.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman what i have to check?

Comment: @Tom I said I will check again! LoL, thanks for this awesome game.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman maybe you know, how to fix my problem?

Comment: @Tom Check out the below answer. I just love your game. Forgot to solve your problem plus I am unable to recreate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have this error, directly witout doing anything

```
if (arrayForBoard[i][j] == 0) {
  let cell = document.createElement("td");
  cell.className = 'blank';
} else {
  let cell = document.createElement("td");
  cell.className = 'tile';
  cell.onclick = moveThisTile(i, j); 
  cell.innerHTML =arrayForBoard[i][j];
}
row.appendChild(cell);
```

You can declare cell outside if/else or call rowAppend cell inside each block

```
let cell = null;
if (arrayForBoard[i][j] == 0) {
  cell = document.createElement("td");
  cell.className = 'blank';
} else {
  cell = document.createElement("td");
  cell.className = 'tile';
  cell.onclick = moveThisTile(i, j); 
  cell.innerHTML =arrayForBoard[i][j];
}
row.appendChild(cell);
```

Comment: yep, exactly my point. but now I get Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: but my problem is not solved, I still have an error rowOffset is not defined at function checkIfMoveable

Comment: Right, you were faster... still trying to clean this code

Comment: Just put `let rowOffset` @Tom

Comment: @farvilain if I put let rowOffset, it return false statement and alert ("ERROR: Cannot move tile! Tile must be next to a blank space.") (function moveThisTile). i can't understand why

Comment: works perfectly for me, still playing the game. But if you plan to ask for every mistake you've done, it could be faster to rewrite everything :/

Comment: @farvilain can you show corrected code please? because it doesn't work for me

Comment: @farvilain like as Victor sad the error now Maximum call stack size exceeded